# Magento newsletter footer text

Tags: magento, newsletter

I want to change the newsletter title: "sign up for our newsletter" on the footer to a different language but I want to keep the original english one, but I can't find anything in static block...which file or block should I edit?

Comment: I'd be glad to help, but I need a little more information. Which theme are you using, and if you have a link to the website in question that would help me pretty significantly as well.

Comment: Turn on Template Path hints under System > Configuration > Developer (choose your store at the top left), then enable Template Path Hints.  Reload the frontend and look at the area you want to modify, it will tell you the exact block you need to edit.

Comment: What do ou mean by "changing the newsletter title but keeping the original english one".Do you mean changing the language according to store view?

Comment: you can use inline translator to change only newsletter title text System->Configuration-> select your store view->Developer-> Translate Inline-> Yes then open the frontend you will see small book icon beside the desired text and click on it and change the text as you wish then submit ->reload you will see the change

Comment: Yes it is according to strore view, thank you for the replies, I applied translate inline, it works thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the translation only, you need to look at

/Your_Package/app/locale/en_US/Mage_Newsletter.csv

en_US = English for US,
en_BR = English for UK and so on.

The title Sign Up for Our Newsletter is not in the XML file but in the PHTML and it's located at

/Your_Package/app/design/frontend/Your_Theme/default/template/newsletter/subscribe.phtml